# How to programmatically get the port jmx is listening to?

Tags: java, port, jmx

I am spawning a few JVM on the same server for some testing.
Their role is to accept a connection from jmxterm to run a method on an Mbean and return a canned result.

To avoid issues with used ports (and avoid cross platform port reusage issues) I decided to start them with **-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0** to allow the OS to give me a free port. This works and I can check those ports through netstat, two for each JVM (one jmxremote and one RMI)

However I am trying to retrieve those ports programmatically so that I can notify the testing app of the spawned JVM's ports so that it can issue those jmxterm commands correctly, as the result will depend on some other details on the JVMs.

I tried grabbing `System.getProperty("com.sun.management.jmxremote.port")` but it just returns 0, from the java arguments. I want the real bound port.

I also tried not specifying any port in the arguments, in which case the above returns Null

tl; dr:
I am starting a jvm with 
**-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=0**
and I want to find programmatically, without using netstat or other system tools what port is the jmxremote bound to